# How to inject custom dependence in custom entity?

Tags: 8, entities

On Drupal 8, in a custom entity class, I'm trying to load a repository in the constructor to be able to use custom functions in the `preSave()`.

```
class MyEntity extends ContentEntityBase implements MyModuleInterface {

private $customStuff;

public function __construct(array $values, $entity_type, &$bundle = FALSE, $translations = []) {
        $this->customStuff = \Drupal::service('mymodule.mymodule_repository');
  }
```

(The service is defined in .services.yml in the correct module)

But I have the error :

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 133 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php). Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager->getDefinition(NULL) (Line: 410)

How to inject custom dependence in custom entity ?

Comment: Drupal core doesn't set an error that matches the one in your question, so either that's not accurate, or a contrib/custom module is causing the problem

Comment: I added the full stack error because yes it's an error provided by Drupal core....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot the take in account the inheritance of the parent __construct().

Here is the solution :

```
  public function __construct(array $values, $entity_type, $bundle = FALSE, $translations = []) {
    parent::__construct($values, $entity_type, $bundle, $translations);
    $this->customStuff = \Drupal::service('mymodule.mymodule_repository');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to inject custom dependence in custom entity?

You cannot; per the [Services and dependency injection](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8) documentation:

> **Note**: It's not possible to inject services to entity object. See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2913224) for more details.

You'll have to get the service from `\Drupal` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Entity annotations? E.g:

```
/**
 * Defines MyEntity entity.
 *
 * @ingroup my_entity
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "my_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("My Entity"),
...
class MyEntity extends ContentEntityBase implements MyModuleInterface {
...
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/structure-of-an-entity-annotation

Comment: Yes annotation are there and the entity is working fine (it's a production code that I trying to improve)

Comment: Ah ok is it the $entity_type parameter in your constructor that doesn't exist?

Comment: Also, if your dependency can be required by composer, initialise a composer project in your module and include the autoload.php, I found that the easiest way of loading dependencies.

Comment: I updated the error. The problem is not composer you should never load autoload in your module, i have to find the right way to load it with Drupal method.

Comment: I've not heard of problems with autoloading in a module, have you got an article to hand explaining? If you have a mismatch of arguments, try using xdebug and trace back to the function that instantiates your class and see what is currently being passed there. I can't imagine you can change what's passed to your constructor, so you may need to amend your code to work with what Drupal gives you.

Comment: You don’t need to include autoload.php - this is all handled for you

Comment: To make your module more modular, would you suggest having it's own composer project with the vendor directory?

 I found that was the best solution, I had to create a content entity and it required a library via composer. Requiring it with Core's composer.json one didn't work for me (the main reason I've done it this way until I look into it more) and two didn't make sense to me in terms of keeping code modular. Because with Core's composer project, wouldn't it get required on every page call?

Thanks in advance!